# Django nested formsets adding forms dynamically

Tags: python, jquery, django-forms, nested-forms, inline-formset

I'm trying to create a survey page using Django that has the functionality to add questions and choices(for each question) dynamically. I have three following model classes: Survey, Question and Choice.

I did a lot of research to figure out how to go about implementing the forms and it seems nested formsets using inline_formsets is the right way to go([I used this tutorial](https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-use-nested-formsets-in-django/)). However, I can't figure out how to add questions and choices dynamically with nested formsets.The JavaScript library that I'm trying to use([This library](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst)) does not have an example for nested formsets and I'm not sure if it supports it.
This code is what i have so far:

forms.py

```
from django.forms import BaseInlineFormSet
from django.forms import HiddenInput
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import *


class SurveyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
        ]


class BaseQuestionFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(BaseQuestionFormset, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.nested = QuestionChoiceFormset(
            instance=form.instance,
            data=form.data if form.is_bound else None,
            files=form.files if form.is_bound else None)

    def is_valid(self):
        result = super(BaseQuestionFormset, self).is_valid()
        print(result)
        if self.is_bound:
            for form in self.forms:
                if hasattr(form, 'nested'):
                    result = result and form.nested.is_valid()

        return result

    def save(self, commit=True):
        for form in self.forms:
            form.save(commit=commit)
        result = super(BaseQuestionFormset, self).save(commit=commit)

        for form in self.forms:
            if hasattr(form, 'nested'):
                if not self._should_delete_form(form):
                    form.nested.save(commit=commit)

        return result


QuestionFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=Survey, model=Question, fields='__all__',
    formset=BaseQuestionFormset, extra=1)
QuestionChoiceFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=Question, model=Choice,
    fields='__all__', extra=1)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def create(request):
    survey = Survey()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        survey_form = SurveyForm(request.POST, instance=survey)
        question_formset = QuestionFormset(
            request.POST, prefix='questions', instance=survey)

        if survey_form.is_valid() and question_formset.is_valid():
            survey_form.save()
            question_formset.save()
            # url = '/preview/{}'.format(survey.pk)
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        survey_form = SurveyForm(instance=survey)
        question_formset = QuestionFormset(instance=survey, prefix='questions')

    context = {
        'survey_form': survey_form,
        'question_formset': question_formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'surveys/create.html', context)
```

create.html

```html
{% extends 'surveys/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block container %}
<div class="container">
  <h1> Create New Survey </h1>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ question_formset.management_form }}
    {{ question_formset.non_form_errors }}
    {{ survey_form.as_p }}
    <table id='myForm1'>
      {% for question_form in question_formset.forms %}
        {{ question_form }}

        {% if question_form.nested %}
          {{ question_form.nested.management_form }}
          {{ question_form.nested.non_form_errors }}
          <div id='myForm2'>
          {% for choice_form in question_form.nested.forms %}
            {{ choice_form }}
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <button type="save">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="{% static "surveys/dist/js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "surveys/dist/js/jquery.formset.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#myForm1').formset({
      prefix: '{{ question_formset.prefix }}',
      formCssClass: 'dynamic-question_formset',
      addText: 'add question'
    });
    $('#myForm2').formset({
      prefix: '{{ choice_form.prefix }}',
      formCssClass: 'dynamic-choice_form',
      addText: 'add choice'
    });
  })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: how are the forms currently displaying? are nested questions all appearing before they shuold or not appearing at all?

Comment: I also dont get the `fields = '__all__'` argument, is it necessary? is it meant to grab `__all__` from some sort of fields class?

Comment: The forms are displaying as expected. But if I try to add questions dynamically they won't save and I get the error: 
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

and Django requires "fields" argument for inline_formset. '__all__' gets all the fields from model class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [this plugin](https://github.com/mbertheau/jquery.django-formset)! It has explanation with examples for nested formsets.

Comment: can you show how you used this library - code/GitHub etc? I have been trying to get the demo example to work (main form, inline form with nested form all on same page) and it just doesn't work - errors out. Also looked at this and couldn't get the demo to run either https://www.yergler.net/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/